# Sync angular items (products)

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, angularjs-ng-repeat

Imagine we have some list of products. We fetch them throught php. For example:

```
$products = Product::all();
```

Then in our view:

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
    <div class='product'>
        <div class="name"><?php echo $product->name ?></div>
        <div class="short-info"><?php echo $product->short ?></div>

        <div class="quantity">
            <button class="add-one">-</button>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $product->quantity ?>">
            <button class="remove-one">+</button>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

In angular we will have some think like this:

```
<div class='product' ng-repeat="product in products">
    <div class="name">{{ product.name }}</div>
    <div class="short-info">{{ product.short }}</div>

    <div class="quantity">
        <button class="add-one" ng-click="removeOne(product)">-</button>
        <input type="text" ng-model="{{ product.quantity }}">
        <button class="remove-one" ng-click="addOne(product)">+</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

But how could we make these things work together?
I want to populate `products` instantly with php (for seo puproses) and have that functional that angular  provides.

```
**EXAMPLE:**
User navigate to http://.../catalog
User instantly see product list (because they were rendered with php)
User instantly can change product amount (here comes angular ng-model)
```

How to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<div class='product' ng-repeat="product in products" ng-init="products=<?php echo json_encode($products);?>">
   <div class="name">{{ product.name }}</div>
   <div class="short-info">{{ product.short }}</div>

    <div class="quantity">
        <button class="add-one" ng-click="removeOne(product)">-</button>
        <input type="text" ng-model="{{ product.quantity }}">
        <button class="remove-one" ng-click="addOne(product)">+</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am not php programmer, but you can get idea here.

Comment: but when you will view the page source ( http://take.ms/626VU ) there will be only angulars template (not rendered products)

Comment: If you correct install angular module with ng-app and use controller, directive ng-init is equivalent of declaring products list in controller. So on page will be list of products with correct binding.

Comment: you can test it yourself and see that it is not. In "Cmd + opt + u" you will not see rendered products because they was rendered via js

Comment: in this case you can create angular directives on server. Example: '<div class="name">{{ product.name }}</div>' will be '<div class="name" ng-init='products[<?php echo index of $product?>]="<?php echo $product->name?>"'>{{ products[<?php echo index of $product?>].name }}</div>'

Comment: or easiest way will be init products like previous answer width ng-init and js index of product for each product the same, then change binding {{ product.short }} to {{ products[index].short }}